# Rails 5 .include? to confirm all string values are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, pg-search

I need to create a custom query for my `product` model.  I am using [pgsearch](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) if that matters.  The code below seems to work, but it just looks aweful.  I need to make sure the products returned from the query have the tags included in the query.

**products_controller.html.erb**

```
...
def index
  if params[:query]
    respond_to do |format|
      if(params[:query].include?('modern') && params[:query].include?('stone') && params[:query].include?('limestone'))
        @products = Product.search_for('modern stone limestone !mouldings !mosaics').order(:name)
        format.html { render layout: 'product/limestone' }
  else
...
```

Comment: What about just `%w[modern stone limestone].all? { |val| params[:query] =~ /#{val}/ }`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma That works.  Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your Ruby version, [this](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11286) might help you.